# Rails 4 universal dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have controller `DashboardController` with empty action `#index`.

Also I have two user's roles. Admin and User. Can I use this action for both user's dashboard?

E.g. rendering different views for each of users. But I need URL like

```
site_name/dashboard
```

How I can realize it?

Answer (score 1):

```
def index 
 if user.admin?
  # code 
  render 'admin_view'
 else
  # code 
  render 'user_view'
 end
end
```